# Laravel app boostraps early in testing environment

Tags: php, laravel, testing, laravel-socialite

Normally, application is [bootstrapped](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v5.3.16/public/index.php#L52-L54) [after](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v5.3.28/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php#L112) request being [created](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v5.3.28/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php#L145). But in a test environment it happens [before](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v5.3.16/tests/TestCase.php#L21) creating request.

That leads to `socialiteproviders/manager` implicitly creating [request](https://github.com/SocialiteProviders/Manager/blob/v2.1.9/src/SocialiteWasCalled.php#L48) [here](https://github.com/laravel/socialite/blob/v2.0.20/src/SocialiteManager.php#L90-L93), thinking it already exists. This request doesn't get used, and [the other one](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v5.3.28/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.php#L575-L578) is created after that.

As a result, I can't forge session data with [`withSession` helper](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v5.3.28/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithSession.php#L15-L20). Since it changes session created for latter request. And SocialiteProviders' provider always gets empty session.

If I disable bootstrapping it [here](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v5.3.16/tests/TestCase.php#L21), the first error I get is [at this line](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v5.3.28/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/DatabaseTransactions.php#L14), since application has not being bootstrapped yet.

Who's at fault? And how to fix it? And can you think of any workarounds meanwhile?

P.S. More details [here](https://github.com/SocialiteProviders/Manager/issues/70).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if I had to answer who's at fault, I'd say it's `socialiteproviders/manager`, since it makes an assumption that request is already created when application is being bootstrapped. And here's [the solution](https://github.com/SocialiteProviders/Manager/compare/master...x-yuri:testing-boot) the way I see it.

To use it you add

```
{
    "type": "vcs",
    "url": "https://github.com/x-yuri/Manager"
}
```

to `repositories` parameter of `composer.json`. And do

```
$ composer require 'socialiteproviders/manager=dev-testing-boot as 2.2.1'
```

Do note though, using extra repositories slows `composer` down.